# Trying to change the INSTALLDIR value to $APPDATA, but won't work

Tags: nsis, minecraft, appdata

I'm trying to make an installer to extract some texture packs and stuff into the AppData folder, but keeps changing to program files.

```
############################################################################################
!define APP_NAME "Optifine+"
!define COMP_NAME "SquirrelKiev"
!define WEB_SITE "https://www.lennyfaces.net/"
!define VERSION "01.02.00.00"
!define COPYRIGHT ""
!define DESCRIPTION "An installer for Optifine and other stuff that I use."
!define LICENSE_TXT "C:\Users\User\Desktop\lisense.txt"
!define INSTALLER_NAME "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Enon\Junk\Modz\test\Optifine.exe"
!define INSTALL_TYPE "SetShellVarContext current"
!define REG_ROOT "HKCU"
!define UNINSTALL_PATH "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${APP_NAME}"

######################################################################

VIProductVersion  "${VERSION}"
VIAddVersionKey "ProductName"  "${APP_NAME}"
VIAddVersionKey "CompanyName"  "${COMP_NAME}"
VIAddVersionKey "LegalCopyright"  "${COPYRIGHT}"
VIAddVersionKey "FileDescription"  "${DESCRIPTION}"
VIAddVersionKey "FileVersion"  "${VERSION}"

######################################################################

SetCompressor LZMA
Name "${APP_NAME}"
Caption "${APP_NAME}"
OutFile "${INSTALLER_NAME}"
BrandingText "${APP_NAME}"
XPStyle on
InstallDirRegKey "${REG_ROOT}" "${UNINSTALL_PATH}" "UninstallString"
InstallDir "$APPDATA\.minecraft"

######################################################################

!include "MUI.nsh"

!define MUI_ABORTWARNING
!define MUI_UNABORTWARNING

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME

!ifdef LICENSE_TXT
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "${LICENSE_TXT}"
!endif

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH

!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_CONFIRM

!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_INSTFILES

!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_FINISH

!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"

######################################################################

Section -MainProgram
${INSTALL_TYPE}
SetOverwrite ifnewer
SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\MCInstaller\launcher_profiles.json"
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\MCInstaller\options.txt"
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\MCInstaller\optionsshaders.txt"
SetOutPath "$INSTDIR\versions\1.12.2-OptiFine_HD_U_C7"
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\MCInstaller\versions\1.12.2-OptiFine_HD_U_C7\1.12.2-OptiFine_HD_U_C7.jar"
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\MCInstaller\versions\1.12.2-OptiFine_HD_U_C7\1.12.2-OptiFine_HD_U_C7.json"
SetOutPath "$INSTDIR\versions\1.12.2"
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\MCInstaller\versions\1.12.2\1.12.2.jar"
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\MCInstaller\versions\1.12.2\1.12.2.json"
SetOutPath "$INSTDIR\shaderpacks"
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\MCInstaller\shaderpacks\Acid Shaders r6.zip"
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\MCInstaller\shaderpacks\Animal Crossing Shaders r6.zip"
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\MCInstaller\shaderpacks\Sildurs Enhanced Default [redone] v1.01.zip"
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\MCInstaller\shaderpacks\Sildurs Vibrant Shaders v1.166 Extreme-Volumetric Lighting.zip"
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\MCInstaller\shaderpacks\Sildurs Vibrant Shaders v1.166 Extreme.zip"
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\MCInstaller\shaderpacks\Sildurs Vibrant Shaders v1.166 High - Motionblur.zip"
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\MCInstaller\shaderpacks\Sildurs Vibrant Shaders v1.166 Lite.zip"
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\MCInstaller\shaderpacks\Sildurs Vibrant Shaders v1.166 Medium.zip"
SetOutPath "$INSTDIR\resourcepacks"
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\MCInstaller\resourcepacks\Faithful 1.12.2-rv4.zip"
SetOutPath "$INSTDIR\libraries\optifine\OptiFine\1.12.2_HD_U_C7"
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\MCInstaller\libraries\optifine\OptiFine\1.12.2_HD_U_C7\OptiFine-1.12.2_HD_U_C7.jar"
SectionEnd

######################################################################

Section -Icons_Reg
SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"
WriteUninstaller "$INSTDIR\uninstall.exe"

WriteRegStr ${REG_ROOT} "${UNINSTALL_PATH}"  "DisplayName" "${APP_NAME}"
WriteRegStr ${REG_ROOT} "${UNINSTALL_PATH}"  "UninstallString" "$INSTDIR\uninstall.exe"
WriteRegStr ${REG_ROOT} "${UNINSTALL_PATH}"  "DisplayVersion" "${VERSION}"
WriteRegStr ${REG_ROOT} "${UNINSTALL_PATH}"  "Publisher" "${COMP_NAME}"

!ifdef WEB_SITE
WriteRegStr ${REG_ROOT} "${UNINSTALL_PATH}"  "URLInfoAbout" "${WEB_SITE}"
!endif
SectionEnd

######################################################################

Section Uninstall
${INSTALL_TYPE}
Delete "$INSTDIR\launcher_profiles.json"
Delete "$INSTDIR\options.txt"
Delete "$INSTDIR\optionsshaders.txt"
Delete "$INSTDIR\versions\1.12.2-OptiFine_HD_U_C7\1.12.2-OptiFine_HD_U_C7.jar"
Delete "$INSTDIR\versions\1.12.2-OptiFine_HD_U_C7\1.12.2-OptiFine_HD_U_C7.json"
Delete "$INSTDIR\versions\1.12.2\1.12.2.jar"
Delete "$INSTDIR\versions\1.12.2\1.12.2.json"
Delete "$INSTDIR\shaderpacks\Acid Shaders r6.zip"
Delete "$INSTDIR\shaderpacks\Animal Crossing Shaders r6.zip"
Delete "$INSTDIR\shaderpacks\Sildurs Enhanced Default [redone] v1.01.zip"
Delete "$INSTDIR\shaderpacks\Sildurs Vibrant Shaders v1.166 Extreme-Volumetric Lighting.zip"
Delete "$INSTDIR\shaderpacks\Sildurs Vibrant Shaders v1.166 Extreme.zip"
Delete "$INSTDIR\shaderpacks\Sildurs Vibrant Shaders v1.166 High - Motionblur.zip"
Delete "$INSTDIR\shaderpacks\Sildurs Vibrant Shaders v1.166 Lite.zip"
Delete "$INSTDIR\shaderpacks\Sildurs Vibrant Shaders v1.166 Medium.zip"
Delete "$INSTDIR\resourcepacks\Faithful 1.12.2-rv4.zip"
Delete "$INSTDIR\libraries\optifine\OptiFine\1.12.2_HD_U_C7\OptiFine-1.12.2_HD_U_C7.jar"
 
RmDir "$INSTDIR\libraries\optifine\OptiFine\1.12.2_HD_U_C7"
RmDir "$INSTDIR\resourcepacks"
RmDir "$INSTDIR\shaderpacks"
RmDir "$INSTDIR\versions\1.12.2"
RmDir "$INSTDIR\versions\1.12.2-OptiFine_HD_U_C7"
 
Delete "$INSTDIR\uninstall.exe"
!ifdef WEB_SITE
Delete "$INSTDIR\${APP_NAME} website.url"
!endif

RmDir "$INSTDIR"

DeleteRegKey ${REG_ROOT} "${UNINSTALL_PATH}"
SectionEnd

######################################################################
```

What do I need to change?

EDIT: Hmm... It's suddenly started working. I tried running it using the test button instead of the EXE. I don't know how that breaks it, and that probably makes me sound stupid, but thats what happened.

Comment: Put the code here. What error did you get?

Comment: @Matthew No error, its just while i was testing it, the install path was program files (x86). I couldn't put the code on the post because stack overflow doesn't allow long code. Here is all i can put: https://pastebin.com/raw/cdwEjsE4

Comment: no worries, its started working now. thanks anyway.

Comment: Never include code or errors as pictures (accessibility problems) or on an external site (the site may go down), instead copy the code into the question and format it as a code block. Questions doing the above are off-topic.

Comment: If something suddenly starts working it can suddenly stop working as well, you need to figure out what you changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more information it is hard to say what is going on but I would recommend that you add `RequestExecutionLevel User` to your script to make sure Windows does not apply compatibility shims to the installer.

`InstallDirRegKey` can trick you if you installed to Program Files during testing on your machine. Make sure that value is not present in the registry when debugging issues like this.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This is something ive needed as if you run it on a student account it won't install.